# Error in applying lemmatization

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, lemmatization

Why am I getting this error, please help.
I am newbie to machine learning.
This is my code and here I've applied lemmatization on 20 newsgroups dataset.
This code aims to get the 500 words with highest counts while applying filtering.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from nltk.corpus import names
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

def letters_only(astr):
    return astr.isalpha()


cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words="english", max_features=500)
groups = fetch_20newsgroups()
cleaned = []
all_names = set(names.words())
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

for post in groups.data:
    cleaned.append(' '.join([lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()
    for word in post.split()
    if letters_only(word) and word not in all_names)]))


transformed = cv.fit_transform(cleaned)
print(cv.get_feature_names())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-91-7158a74bae71>", line 18, in <module>
    for word in post.split()

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\stem\wordnet.py", line 40, in lemmatize
    lemmas = wordnet._morphy(word, pos)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py", line 1712, in _morphy
    forms = apply_rules([form])

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py", line 1692, in apply_rules
    for form in forms

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py", line 1694, in <listcomp>
    if form.endswith(old)]

AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Comment: where is `form.endswith(old)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but turning that for loop one liner into regular for loop solved the problem;

```
for post in groups.data:
    for word in post.split():
        if letters_only(word) and word not in all_names:
            cleaned.append(' '.join([lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower())]))
```